# Efficiently dealing with repeated values within a by group using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

What's the preferred way of getting a single value from a column (`variable`) that is repeated (ie the same value in every row) within by-groups? Should I use `variable[1]` or should I include that variable in the by statement and use `.BY$variable`? Let's assume that I want the return value to include `variable` as column.

It seems pretty clearly from the following tests that putting additional variables in the `by` statement slows things down, even discounting the cost of keying by that new variable (or using trickery to tell `data.table` that no additional keying is necessary). Why is it that additional already-keyed `by` variables slow things down?

I guess I had hoped that including already-keyed `by` variables would be a convenient syntactical trick to including those variables in the return data.table without explicitly naming them in the `j` statement, but it seems like this is inadvisable since there is some sort of overhead associated with additional by variable, even if they're already keyed. So my question is, what causes this overhead?

Some example data:

```
library(data.table)
n <- 1e8
y <- data.table(sample(1:5,n,replace=TRUE),rnorm(n),rnorm(n))
y[,sumV2:=sum(V2),keyby=V1]
```

Timing shows that using the approach using `variable[1]` (in this case, `sumV2[1]`) is faster.

```
x <- copy(y)
system.time(x[, list(out=sum(V3*V2)/sumV2[1],sumV2[1]),keyby=V1])
system.time(x[, list(out=sum(V3*V2)/.BY$sumV2),keyby=list(V1,sumV2)])
```

I guess this is not surprising, since `data.table` has no way of knowing that the groups defined by setkey(V1) and setkey(V1,sumV2) are actually identical.

What I do find surprising is that even if the data.table is keyed on `setkey(V1,sumV2)` (and we entirely ignore the time it takes to set the new key), using `sumV2[1]` is still faster. Why is this?

```
x <- copy(y)
setkey(x,V1,sumV2)
system.time(x[, list(out=sum(V3*V2)/sumV2[1],sumV2[1]),by=V1])
system.time(x[, list(out=sum(V3*V2)/.BY$sumV2),by=list(V1,sumV2)])
```

Plus, the time it takes to do `setkey(x,V2,sumV2)` is non-negligible. Is there any way to trick data.table into skipping actually rekeying x by just telling it that the key isn't actually changing substantively?

```
x <- copy(y)
system.time(setkey(x,V1,sumV2))
```

Answering my own question, it seems like we can skip sorting when setting key just by assigning the "sorted" attribute. Is this allowed? Will it break things?

```
x <- copy(y)
system.time({
  setattr(x, "sorted", c("V1","sumV2"))
  x[, list(out=sum(V3*V2)/.BY$sumV2),by=list(V1,sumV2)]
})
```

Whether it's bad practice or could potentially break things, I do not know. But using `setattr` trickery is considerably faster than explicit keying:

```
x <- copy(y)
system.time({
  setkey(x,V1,sumV2)
  x[, list(out=sum(V3*V2)/.BY$sumV2),by=list(V1,sumV2)]
})
```

but even using `setattr` trickery combined with using `sumV2` in the by statement is still not as a fast as leaving `sumV2` out of the by statement entirely:

```
x <- copy(y)
system.time(x[, list(out=sum(V3*V2)/sumV2[1],sumV2[1]),keyby=V1])
```

It seems to me that using setting key via attributes and using sumV2 as a length-1 by variable within each group *should* be faster than only keying on V1 and using sumV2[1]. If `sumV2` isn't specified as a `by` variable, then the entire vector of repeated values in `sumV2` needs to get generated for each group prior to being subsetted to `sumV2[1]`. Compare this to when `sumV2` is a `by` variable, there is only a length-1 vector for `sumV2` in each group. Obviously my reasoning here is incorrect. Can anyone explain why? Why is `sumV2[1]` is the fastest option even compared to making `sumV2` a by variable after using `setattr` trickery?

As an aside, I was surprised to learn that using `attr<-` was no slower than `setattr` (both instantaneous, implying no copying at all). This is contrary to my understanding that base R `foo<-` functions make copies of the data.

```
x <- copy(y)
system.time(setattr(x, "sorted", c("V1","sumV2")))
x <- copy(y)
system.time(attr(x,"sorted") <- c("V1","sumV2"))
```

relevant `SessionInfo()` used for this question:

```
data.table version 1.12.2
R version 3.5.3
```

Comment: I'm not sure I get it. Since you're using `:=` and `keyby` to create `sumV2`, `x` ends up already keyed by `V1` after `x[,sumV2:=sum(V2),keyby=V1]`, and `data.table` knows this. You can corroborate by calling `key(x)` *before* calling `setkey`, or setting `verbose=TRUE` in the call to `setkey` (in your last example).

Comment: Your example does not need a by clause. V3*V2/sumV2 can be run directly as a vectorized operation.

Comment: @Frank--oops I forgot to wrap V3*V2 in the sum function. The idea here is taking a weighted average of values of V3 by weights defined by V2 in categories defined by V1. I edited the question to fix this.

Comment: I'll add that this is all a bit of a strawman since the fastest approach is probably not to create `sumV2` as a column of x at all and instead have a single compound `j` statement in which `sumV2` is created as a temporary variable in j and used to calculate the weighted average. But it's conceivable that you might *both* want the repeated values of `sumV2` in `x` and another shorted data.table containing the resulting weighted averages.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I don't have a great technical answer but I think I've figured this out conceptually with the help of `options(datatable.verbose=TRUE)`

Create the data

```
library(data.table)
n <- 1e8

y_unkeyed_5groups <- data.table(sample(1:10000,n,replace=TRUE),rnorm(n),rnorm(n))
y_unkeyed_5groups[,sumV2:=sum(V2),keyby=V1]
y_unkeyed_10000groups <- data.table(sample(1:10000,n,replace=TRUE),rnorm(n),rnorm(n))
y_unkeyed_10000groups[,sumV2:=sum(V2),keyby=V1]
```

run the slow way

```
x <- copy(y)
system.time({
  setattr(x, "sorted", c("V1","sumV2"))
  x[, list(out=sum(V3*V2)/.BY$sumV2),by=list(V1,sumV2)]
})
# Detected that j uses these columns: V3,V2 
# Finding groups using uniqlist on key ... 1.050s elapsed (1.050s cpu) 
# Finding group sizes from the positions (can be avoided to save RAM) ... 0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 
# lapply optimization is on, j unchanged as 'list(sum(V3 * V2)/.BY$sumV2)'
# GForce is on, left j unchanged
# Old mean optimization is on, left j unchanged.
# Making each group and running j (GForce FALSE) ... 
# memcpy contiguous groups took 0.305s for 6 groups
# eval(j) took 0.254s for 6 calls
# 0.560s elapsed (0.510s cpu) 
# user  system elapsed 
# 1.81    0.09    1.72
```

run the fast way:

```
x <- copy(y)
system.time(x[, list(out=sum(V3*V2)/sumV2[1],sumV2[1]),keyby=V1])
# Detected that j uses these columns: V3,V2,sumV2 
# Finding groups using uniqlist on key ... 0.060s elapsed (0.070s cpu) 
# Finding group sizes from the positions (can be avoided to save RAM) ... 0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 
# lapply optimization is on, j unchanged as 'list(sum(V3 * V2)/sumV2[1], sumV2[1])'
# GForce is on, left j unchanged
# Old mean optimization is on, left j unchanged.
# Making each group and running j (GForce FALSE) ... 
# memcpy contiguous groups took 0.328s for 6 groups
# eval(j) took 0.291s for 6 calls
# 0.610s elapsed (0.580s cpu) 
# user  system elapsed 
# 1.08    0.08    0.82
```

The `finding groups` part is the cause of the difference. I'm guessing what's going on here is that setting a `key` is really just sorting (I should have guessed from how the attribute is named!) and doesn't actually do anything to define where groups start and end. So even though `data.table` knows that `sumV2` is sorted, it doesn't know that it's all the same value and therefore has to find where the groups within `sumV2` start and end.

My guess that it would be technically possible to write `data.table` in a way where keying doesn't just sort but actually stores the start/end rows of each group within keyed variables, but that this could potentially take up a lot of memory for data.tables with lots of groups.

Knowing this, it seems like the recommendation might be to not repeat the same by statement over and over again and instead do everything you need to do in a single by statement.  This is probably a good recommendation in general, but is not the case with a small number of groups. See the following counterexample:

I rewrote this in what I assumed would be the fastest possible way using data.table (only a single by statement, and making use of GForce):

```
library(data.table)
n <- 1e8
y_unkeyed_5groups <- data.table(sample(1:5,n, replace=TRUE),rnorm(n),rnorm(n))
y_unkeyed_10000groups <- data.table(sample(1:10000,n, replace=TRUE),rnorm(n),rnorm(n))

x <- copy(y_unkeyed_5groups)
system.time({
  x[, product:=V3*V2]
  outDT <- x[,list(sumV2=sum(V2),sumProduct=sum(product)),keyby=V1]
  outDT[,`:=`(out=sumProduct/sumV2,sumProduct=NULL) ]
  setkey(x,V1)
  x[outDT,sumV2:=sumV2,all=TRUE]
  x[,product:=NULL]
  outDT
})

# Detected that j uses these columns: V3,V2 
# Assigning to all 100000000 rows
# Direct plonk of unnamed RHS, no copy.
# Detected that j uses these columns: V2,product 
# Finding groups using forderv ... 0.350s elapsed (0.810s cpu) 
# Finding group sizes from the positions (can be avoided to save RAM) ... 0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 
# lapply optimization is on, j unchanged as 'list(sum(V2), sum(product))'
# GForce optimized j to 'list(gsum(V2), gsum(product))'
# Making each group and running j (GForce TRUE) ... 1.610s elapsed (4.550s cpu) 
# Detected that j uses these columns: sumProduct,sumV2 
# Assigning to all 5 rows
# RHS for item 1 has been duplicated because NAMED is 3, but then is being plonked. length(values)==2; length(cols)==2)
# forder took 0.98 sec
# reorder took 3.35 sec
# Starting bmerge ...done in 0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 
# Detected that j uses these columns: sumV2 
# Assigning to 100000000 row subset of 100000000 rows
# Detected that j uses these columns: product 
# Assigning to all 100000000 rows
# user  system elapsed 
# 11.00    1.75    5.33 


x2 <- copy(y_unkeyed_5groups)
system.time({
  x2[,sumV2:=sum(V2),keyby=V1]
  outDT2 <- x2[, list(sumV2=sumV2[1],out=sum(V3*V2)/sumV2[1]),keyby=V1]
})
# Detected that j uses these columns: V2 
# Finding groups using forderv ... 0.310s elapsed (0.700s cpu) 
# Finding group sizes from the positions (can be avoided to save RAM) ... 0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 
# lapply optimization is on, j unchanged as 'sum(V2)'
# Old mean optimization is on, left j unchanged.
# Making each group and running j (GForce FALSE) ... 
# collecting discontiguous groups took 0.714s for 5 groups
# eval(j) took 0.079s for 5 calls
# 1.210s elapsed (1.160s cpu) 
# setkey() after the := with keyby= ... forder took 1.03 sec
# reorder took 3.21 sec
# 1.600s elapsed (3.700s cpu) 
# Detected that j uses these columns: sumV2,V3,V2 
# Finding groups using uniqlist on key ... 0.070s elapsed (0.070s cpu) 
# Finding group sizes from the positions (can be avoided to save RAM) ... 0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 
# lapply optimization is on, j unchanged as 'list(sumV2[1], sum(V3 * V2)/sumV2[1])'
# GForce is on, left j unchanged
# Old mean optimization is on, left j unchanged.
# Making each group and running j (GForce FALSE) ... 
# memcpy contiguous groups took 0.347s for 5 groups
# eval(j) took 0.265s for 5 calls
# 0.630s elapsed (0.620s cpu) 
# user  system elapsed 
# 6.57    0.98    3.99 

all.equal(x,x2)
# TRUE
all.equal(outDT,outDT2)
# TRUE
```

Ok, well it turns out that the efficiency gained by not repeating by statements and using GForce doesn't matter that much when there are only 5 groups. But for a larger number of groups this does make a difference, (although I haven't written this in a way to separate out the benefits using just one by statement and NOT GForce versus the benefits of using GForce and multiple by statements):

```
x <- copy(y_unkeyed_10000groups)
system.time({
  x[, product:=V3*V2]
  outDT <- x[,list(sumV2=sum(V2),sumProduct=sum(product)),keyby=V1]
  outDT[,`:=`(out=sumProduct/sumV2,sumProduct=NULL) ]
  setkey(x,V1)
  x[outDT,sumV2:=sumV2,all=TRUE]
  x[,product:=NULL]
  outDT
})
# 
# Detected that j uses these columns: V3,V2 
# Assigning to all 100000000 rows
# Direct plonk of unnamed RHS, no copy.
# Detected that j uses these columns: V2,product 
# Finding groups using forderv ... 0.740s elapsed (1.220s cpu) 
# Finding group sizes from the positions (can be avoided to save RAM) ... 0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 
# lapply optimization is on, j unchanged as 'list(sum(V2), sum(product))'
# GForce optimized j to 'list(gsum(V2), gsum(product))'
# Making each group and running j (GForce TRUE) ... 0.810s elapsed (2.390s cpu) 
# Detected that j uses these columns: sumProduct,sumV2 
# Assigning to all 10000 rows
# RHS for item 1 has been duplicated because NAMED is 3, but then is being plonked. length(values)==2; length(cols)==2)
# forder took 1.97 sec
# reorder took 11.95 sec
# Starting bmerge ...done in 0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 
# Detected that j uses these columns: sumV2 
# Assigning to 100000000 row subset of 100000000 rows
# Detected that j uses these columns: product 
# Assigning to all 100000000 rows
# user  system elapsed 
# 18.37    2.30    7.31 

x2 <- copy(y_unkeyed_10000groups)
system.time({
  x2[,sumV2:=sum(V2),keyby=V1]
  outDT2 <- x[, list(sumV2=sumV2[1],out=sum(V3*V2)/sumV2[1]),keyby=V1]
})

# Detected that j uses these columns: V2 
# Finding groups using forderv ... 0.770s elapsed (1.490s cpu) 
# Finding group sizes from the positions (can be avoided to save RAM) ... 0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 
# lapply optimization is on, j unchanged as 'sum(V2)'
# Old mean optimization is on, left j unchanged.
# Making each group and running j (GForce FALSE) ... 
# collecting discontiguous groups took 1.792s for 10000 groups
# eval(j) took 0.111s for 10000 calls
# 3.960s elapsed (3.890s cpu) 
# setkey() after the := with keyby= ... forder took 1.62 sec
# reorder took 13.69 sec
# 4.660s elapsed (14.4s cpu) 
# Detected that j uses these columns: sumV2,V3,V2 
# Finding groups using uniqlist on key ... 0.070s elapsed (0.070s cpu) 
# Finding group sizes from the positions (can be avoided to save RAM) ... 0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 
# lapply optimization is on, j unchanged as 'list(sumV2[1], sum(V3 * V2)/sumV2[1])'
# GForce is on, left j unchanged
# Old mean optimization is on, left j unchanged.
# Making each group and running j (GForce FALSE) ... 
# memcpy contiguous groups took 0.395s for 10000 groups
# eval(j) took 0.284s for 10000 calls
# 0.690s elapsed (0.650s cpu) 
# user  system elapsed 
# 20.49    1.67   10.19 

all.equal(x,x2)
# TRUE
all.equal(outDT,outDT2)
# TRUE
```

More generally, data.table is blazingly fast, but in order to extract the fastest and most efficient computation that makes best use of the underlying C code, you need to pay particular attention to the internals of how data.table works. I recently learned about GForce optimization in data.table and it seems that specific forms of j statements (involving simple functions like mean and sum) are parsed and executed directly in C when there's a by statement.